# c++ expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, cin, std

```
int main ( ) {

   std::cout << "Enter a : "; // просим пользователя ввести любое число
   int a = 0;
   std::cin >> a; // получаем пользовательское число и сохраняем его в переменную a


    std::cout << "Enter b: "; // просим пользователя ввести любое число
   const CHAR* b;
   (b) << std::cin; // получаем пользовательское число и сохраняем его в переменную b
   return 0;
```

Не стандартный std::cin нужен для полной работы кода в дальнейшем. 
Когда пытаюсь скомплиировать пишет ошибку "expected primary-expression before ')' token"
Как бы не пытался ничего не помогает. Помогите понять в чём проблема.

Comment: А что вы хотите получить с помощью `^`?

Comment: что это вообще за синтаксис такой?

Comment: Это лишнее, нужно убрать

Comment: https://www.twirpx.com/file/11126/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main ( ) {
    std::cout << "Enter a : ";
    int a = 0;
    std::cin >> a;
```

Тут у вас все правильно

```
std::cout << "Enter b: ";
const char* b;            // char - маленькими буквами!
                          // const ненужен - не будет читать
```

Если вам таки нужна строка, то надо выделить память для нее, например

```
char b[100];
```

или

```
char * b = new char[100];
```

Вот так

```
(b) << std::cin;
```

бесполезно, читать надо в другую сторону:

```
std::cin >> b;
```

Еще лучше

```
std::string b;
std::cin >> b;
```